# Meter fila de una tabla, en otra tabla Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas estoy haciendo la edición de un pedido, y se puede componer con varias filas. Una vez cargo el editar un pedido, hago un foreach para sacar todos los articulos que tiene en el pedido, ya sea una fila o más de una, depende del pedido. Además le pongo un contador, para saber en que fila estoy.

```
<table id="tabla" style="width: 100%;">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th class="thTxt padLeftProducto">Producto</th>
                <th class="thTxt">Opción</th>
                <th class="thTxt">Precio</th>
                <th class="thTxt">Cantidad</th>
                <th class="thTxt">Total</th>
                <th></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                
            @php $contador =1 @endphp
            @foreach ($pedidos as $key => $ped)
                <tr data-fila="{{ $contador }}" id="InputsWrapper">
                    <td class="lupaEditar">
                        <a href="#add-producto" data-toggle="modal" class="aLupa"><i class="fas fa-search-plus" style="color: #0044cc;"></i></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control inpuPed21 idProducto" name="eProducto[]" value="{{ $ped->producto }}" autocomplete="off">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control inpuPed21 laOpcion" name="eTipo[]" value="{{ $ped->opcion }}" autocomplete="off">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if ($idUser->tipo_id == 3)
                            @php
                                $nuevoPrecio = ($ped->precio*21/100)+$ped->precio;
                            @endphp
                        @else
                            @php
                                $nuevoPrecio = $ped->precio;
                            @endphp
                        @endif
                        <input type="text" class="form-control inpuPed21 inputcalculo  ePrecioUnid" name="ePrecioUnid[]" value="{{number_format($nuevoPrecio, 2)}}" autocomplete="off">
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 85px;"><input type="text" class="form-control inpuPed21 inputcalculo cntComprada" name="cntComprada[]" value="{{ $ped->cantidad }}" autocomplete="off"></td>
                    <td>
                        @if ($idUser->tipo_id == 3)
                            @php
                                $nuevoSubtotal = ($ped->subtotal*21/100)+$ped->subtotal;
                            @endphp
                        @else
                            @php
                                $nuevoSubtotal = $ped->subtotal;
                            @endphp
                        @endif
                        <input type="text" class="form-control inpuPed21 inputcalculo eSubTotal" name="eSubTotal[]" value="{{number_format($nuevoSubtotal, 2)}}" autocomplete="off">
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 40px;"><a href="#"><i class="far fa-trash-alt iconTask"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
                @php $contador= $contador + 1; @endphp

            @endforeach
                    <div id="top1221" style="display: none;">{{$idUser->tipo_id}}</div>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**Luego tengo el botón para añadir una fila**

```
<div class="padBtnAddFila">
  <div class="pull-right" style="margin-top: 1%;">
      <a href="#" id="add" class="btnAddFila"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Añadir fila</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Si podes ver al principio de cada fila, tengo un botón que añade un modal:**

```
<td class="lupaEditar">
   <a href="#add-producto" data-toggle="modal" class="aLupa"><i class="fas fa-search-plus" style="color: #0044cc;"></i></a>
</td>
```

**El modal que abro es el siguiente**
Donde muestro todos los producto que puedo elegir.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add-producto" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body" id="dialog-form-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12" style="padding: 0px;">
                    
                    <table class="table table-hover" id="productosBase">
                        <h3 class="productosBaseh3">Selecciona producto</h3>
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Producto</th>
                            <th scope="col">Opción</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="txtRight">Precio</th>
                            <th></th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        @php $contadorModal =1 @endphp
                        @foreach ($productos as $key => $pro)
                        
                          <tr data-fila="{{ $contadorModal }}" id="filaModal">
                            <th scope="row">{{ $pro->name }}</th>
                            <td style="padding: 0px 10px!important;">
                                @if (count($pro->combinations))
                                    <select class="form-control selectModal combinationSelect" name="">
                                        <option value="" selected>Selecciona una opción </option>
                                    @foreach ($pro->combinations as $item)
                                        @php $str = substr($item->combination, 13); @endphp
                                        @php $namePro = ucfirst($str); @endphp
                                        <option value="{{ $item->id}}"}> {{str_replace("-"," ",$namePro)}} </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                @endif
                            </td>
                            <td class="txtRight precioCombi"> 
                                @if (count($pro->combinations))
                                    -
                                @else
                                    @if ($pro->oferta == 0.00)
                                        {{ number_format($pro->precio, 2) }}
                                    @else
                                        {{ number_format($pro->oferta, 2) }}
                                    @endif
                                @endif
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a class="btn btnAddPro">Añadir</a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        @php $contadorModal= $contadorModal + 1; @endphp
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Para añadir una fila nueva en la tabla principal utilizo este código:

```
    var numeroFila = $("#InputsWrapper");
    var x = InputsWrapper.length;
    //Esta función añade una nueva fila//

    $('#add').click(function(event) {
        $("#tabla").each(function() {
        x++;
        var tds = '<tr data-fila='+x+' id="InputsWrapper">';       
        jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function(index, element) {
            var html = $(this).html();
            if(index == 0){
                html = '<a href="#add-producto" data-toggle="modal" class="aLupa"><i class="fas fa-search-plus" style="color: #0044cc;"></i></a>';
            }
            if(index == 1){
                html = '<input type="text" class="form-control inpuPed21 idProducto" name="eProducto[]" autocomplete="off">';
            }
            if(index == 2){
                html = '<input type="text" class="form-control inpuPed21 laOpcion" name="eTipo[]" value="" autocomplete="off">';
            }
            if(index == 3){
                html = '<input type="text" class="form-control inpuPed21 inputcalculo  ePrecioUnid" name="ePrecioUnid[]" value="" autocomplete="off">';
            }
            if(index == 4){
                html = '<input type="text" class="form-control inpuPed21 inputcalculo cntComprada" name="cntComprada[]" value="1" autocomplete="off">';
            }
            if(index == 5){
                html = '<input type="text" class="form-control inpuPed21 inputcalculo eSubTotal" name="eSubTotal[]" value="" autocomplete="off">';
            }
            if(index == 6){
                html = '<a href="#"><i class="far fa-trash-alt iconTask"></i></a>';
            }
            tds += '<td>' + html+ '</td>';
        });
        tds += '</tr>';
        if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
            $('tbody', this).append(tds);
        } else {
            $(this).append(tds);
        }
        });
        var envio = $('#elEnvio').val()
            if(envio == 'undefined'){
            envio = 0;
            return envio;
            }
            actualizarTotales(envio);
    });
```

Entonces lo que necesito es que cuando en el modal, le de al botón `<a class="btn btnAddPro">Añadir</a>` se me inserte en la tabla principal, cada cosa a sus sitio. Eso es posible??

Comment: Es posible y habitual, añadir nuevas filas a una tabla al realizar alguna acción. Creo que tienes dos estrategias a seguir: al pulsar ese botón enviar los datos relacionados al *backend*, guardarlos en tu fuente de datos y que se recargue la página (los cargas en un `form` oculto por ejemplo y lo envías (POST). La segunda, puedes o no enviar los datos al *backend*, usando *Ajax* o similar, yo suelo usar *fetch* y recibida la respuesta positiva, "construyes" una fila y la añades a la tabla. Puedes construir esta fila y agregarla sin necesidad de enviar los datos, ya depende de tus requisitos.

Comment: Prefiriria utilizar el fetch, no quiero recargar ni guardar hasta que no esté completado, puedes ayudarme a como aplicar el fetch tal como lo tengo?? @Orici

Comment: Esque no encuentro como traer los datos que tengo en esa fila, para luego insertarla en la otra @Orici